# pytest: option via command line and INI file

Tags: pytest

I'd like to be able to configure tests via both `*.ini` file and command line.

`addopts` cannot help: having many options in one line is scary.

There is also `addini` but it requires duplication and more checks on tests invocation.

I also can wrap `addoption` function, in which I get default value from some file, but I wouldn't see it in `pytest --help` output. Making something more complex on top of pytest doesn't worth it.

Are there any other options?

Comment: If the option should be assignable from both cli and ini file, you will have to do the checks yourself as this is what `pytest` also does. Also, when reading the option, don't forget to handle the case when the value is both set in ini and provided via cli and what to do when they differ.

Comment: If you are looking for an example, [check out option handling in the `_pytest.logging` module](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/logging.py#L79).

Comment: @hoefling Thank you. That's similar to what I've ended up doing.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov: did you have a look at `tox`? You can put your main configuration into `.ini` file and also pass other options via command line.

Comment: @kchomski Haven't looked by now but definitely will do.